# Flyway maven plugin: Error, no migration could be resolved in the configured locations

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I am using flyway latest version, 9.3.0, to create tables in a postgres database which has many different schemas. However, my problem is related to locations parameter. I am using external cofiguration where i specify locations as:

`flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration/schema_name`

but I get the following error:

`[ERROR] Schema "public" has version 5.0.1, but no migration could be resolved in the configured locations !`

Here is my public.conf, which is the file i choose when running mvn migrate -Dflyway.configFiles=public.conf (schema = public):

```
flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql....
flyway.user=my-user
flyway.password=password
flyway.defaultSchema=public
flyway.baselineOnMigrate=true
flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration/public
```

[image: Resources with sql scripts]

The last and new script is not found...

Anyone can help?

Comment: Did you try configuring the location(s) using a property file like explained in Spring's [How-to Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.migration-tool), e.g. `spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration/public` where "public" is the subfolder containing scripts?

Comment: @hc_dev thanks for your suggestion. I think I can't go for this approach since I have multiple schemas and I need to run migrate command multiple times. If I tell spring to launch mifration on startup, I can only migrate one schema. It makes sense?

Comment: I tried locations=filesystem:src/main/resources/db/migration/public and it worked. This could be a workaround although is not what I want...